# Find plane equation based on tangent plane equation (both planes are parallel)?

Tags: calculus, plane-curves, tangent-line

I' m asked to find the plane equation for **(x,y,z)-> 0,0,0.**

I' m given the following function: $$f(x,y)=e^{x^{2}}+\ln(\frac{1}{xy})$$
Also the task specifies that the origin plane is parallel with the tangent plane and passes through the following point **(x,y,z)->(1,1,e)** (tangent plane)

I've found the tangent plane equation (after doing the partial derivatives) and the equation is :$$x(2e-1)+y-z-(e+2)=0$$ (Implicit form).

How do I find the plane passing through (0,0,0), origin,  given that I have now the tangent plane equation? Can I just copy the coefficients and write **0** at the end since they are parallel?
Like this perhaps: $$x(2e-1)+y-z=0$$

Comment: Yes. A plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is always parallel to $ax+by+cz=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approch is right, and but I got different numbers: the plane tangent at $P=(1,1,f(1,1))=(1,1,e)$ should be
$$F_x(P)(x-1)+F_y(P)(y-1)+F_z(P)(z-e)=0\quad \Rightarrow\quad (2e-1)x-y-z-(e-2)=0$$
where $F(x,y,z)=z-e^{x^2}+\ln(xy)$ and
$(F_x,F_y,F_z)=(-2xe^{x^2}+1/x,1/y,1)$.

Hence the parallel plane through $(0,0,0)$ is $(2e-1)x-y-z=0$.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that I've misscalculated something. Tnx for the answer!

Comment: Could you please explain how you go z to be: 2e+1? I just get e, by putting x=1 and y=1 to the given function, simple as that...

Comment: @wesewx Your given point is $(1,1,2e+1)$. Check your question.

Comment: @omg, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @wesewx So the given point is $(1,1,e)$ and not $(1,1,2e+1)$.
Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes, that's right...